# Similar to __construct but called on each newly called function within a class

Tags: php, function, class

I have 3 files below:

**controller.php**

```php
class inject{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'I say';
    }
}
```

**model.php**

```php
class say extends inject{
    public function init(){
        echo ' hello ';
        $this->otherFunction();
    }
    public function otherFunction(){
        //parent::__construct(); --> This should't be added manually
        echo ' world ';
    }
}
```

**view.php**

```php
$output = new say();
$output->init(); //UPDATED
```

Without modifying functions inside class "say" (which I did above), I want everytime I call function init(), it will produce "I say hello I say world". How I do that?

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ZVoZW)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: @Eakethet My problem doesn't have relation will function __call or __callStatic. However it kinda like function __construct. While __construct is called on every created class, I want something similar to __construct that will be called on every created function.

Comment: Well, so you have a big problem, because function is not "created"... :D
Also you dont need that 'echo $output->init();', you do the echo in this function

Comment: My apologize, I mean when function is called

Comment: @Eakethet Yeah, this is just a pseudocode, so I created it without long thinking. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add new features to a class without modifying it, you can use a decorator pattern.

```
<?php
class inject{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'I say';
    }
}

class say extends inject{
    public function init(){
        echo ' hello ';
        $this->otherFunction();
    }
    public function otherFunction(){
        echo ' world ';
    }
}

class DecoratorSay extends say
{
    public function otherFunction() {
        parent::__construct();
        parent::otherFunction();
    }
}

$output = new DecoratorSay();
echo $output->init();
```

**Output**

```
I say hello I say world
```

Answer (score 0):

You should think about if you really need this. This can be done by overloading and making methods private/protected.

example:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public function __call($function, $arguments)
    {
        echo 'I chose ';
        $this->$function(...$arguments);
    }

    private function bar(): void
    {
        echo 'bar' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function baz(): void
    {
        echo 'baz' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
$foo->baz();
```

Comment: How if I call baz() inside bar() but I want the result will be "I choose bar I choose baz"?

Comment: Then you should look for something different, not doing something everytime function is called. use another function which will recieve argument of string you want to append after "I chose" and instead of echo 'baz' call this function $this->printOut('baz') or so on